# use ls > filelist and change file list content to file list

Tags: ls

I need to use the `ls > filelist` and, however when is use `"cat filelist"` it displays all the content in the `filelist` with `filelist` as one of the names in it, but i need to change it `"* * * File List * * *"`. I am unsure how to do this only to the `filelist` in file list if that makes sense.

Comment: Do you really have a space between `file` and `list`?

Comment: I'm sorry for confusion, but the answer to your question is no.

Comment: Don't redirect to a file in the same directory you're listing, since the redirection creates the file before starting `ls`.

Comment: well see thats what i have to do for this question, as a hint i was told to use grep -v, which makes sense a little because it gets rid of the filelist in filelist so it looks like ***File List***

Comment: this is a question on my homework that i was working on but can't seem to finish it, i get confused on the part when i do ls > filelist  and the cat filelist when the contents are displayed one of them is filelist and i need to get rid of that when.

Comment: On a side note: please be aware of [why not to parse ls](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls). The homework should be aware of this or mention it at least. Well save the read for later.

Comment: alright so i was able to do with ls | grep -v filelist > filelist  and then echo "***File List***" >> filelist. however it shows up at the end of the text file, how can i make it go to the top of the text file when everything is displayed on screen. i think i need to use pipe

Comment: i need a title line is what the homework question wants me to do

Answer (score 0):

```
ls > /tmp/filelist
echo "* * *  File List  * * *"
cat /tmp/filelist
```

assumes you are not listing the files in `/tmp`. If that is the case change the `/tmp` to `/var/tmp`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
ls | grep -vx filelist > filelist
```

The `-v` option makes it exclude the matching lines from the output, and `-x` makes it match the whole line (so it won't skip `otherfilelist`).

Answer (score 0):

The Unix commands are quite terse, and don't decorate their output with headers/footers or irrelevant details, precisely to make their use in random pipelines easier. Adding such is quite easy:

```
(echo '* * * This is a header * * *'; ls ; echo --* footer *--) > filelist
```

Comment: `(echo "***File List***"; ls | grep -v filelist;)> filelist`   This is what I used and got the right answer through you really really great hint, thanks again but when it comes to pipes does it go in order such as starting echo then doing the `ls`  and doing it only do `>filelist`? any help with pipes is great, i will however also read more into it in textbook

Answer (score 0):

Just for deeper understanding : You can easily split up the whole command three parts:

1. echo "***File List***";
   echo prints out ( if you don't have pipe the output elsewhere ) on STDIN ( Standard Input )
2. ls | grep -vx filelist;
   lists the content of your current directory and pipes the output to grep. Normally "grep" would just print lines which contains the given keyword ( "filelist") in our case. With the option -v we are looking for lines which does NOT contain the keyword. As mentioned by Barmar , it would also exclude files which contain "filelist" like e.g. "myfilelist", "filelist2", ... , so the usage of the -x is recommended.
3. > filelist 
   >   redirects the output to the file "filelist". As (1) and (2) are in brackets and seperated by semicolons, the output (which would have been printed out on STDIN) of both commands will be redirected to this file.